# How to save copy of Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, save

I've been trying to make a macro that automatically saves a backup copy of my Excel workbook before I edit any of its data.

Every time I call it, even though it successfully saves a new copy, when it reaches the end the code stops execution, and macros I try to call below it don't execute.

I think when I run the code and the new backup version is created, the code continues to run on the *backup workbook* instead of the main workbook, so when I close the backup workbook I abruptly end the code.

I'd like to save a backup version of my main workbook, close the backup version and continue the code on the main workbook.

```vb
Public Sub BackupWorkbook()

Dim CurrentFile As String, BackupFile As String, DesiredWorkbookName As String
Dim NowDate As String

'Save current code and Excel spreadsheet data
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Get necessary strings for filenames
CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

NowDate = Replace(Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"), ":", ".")
BackupFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Chem Chart Backups" & "\" & "Chemical Chart" _
                & " (" & NowDate & ")" & ".xlsm"

'Save as active workbook to backup file location, then reopen main workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs BackupFile, FileFormat:=52

Workbooks.Open CurrentFile

'This should close the backup version of workbook that opened because of SaveAs method
Workbooks(DesiredWorkbookName & " (" & NowDate & ")" & ".xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

```
Public Sub TestMacros()

Call BackupWorkbook

'If this message box pops up after macro is called, it is successful
MsgBox "Success!" 

End Sub
```

Comment: Use save copy. Renaming a open workbook is not going to work

Comment: I don't really understand, the only thing my code ends up renaming is the backup workbook. I tried to use the SaveCopyAs method instead, but unfortunately I get the same result. A backup workbook is saved successfully, and the main workbook is the only one that stays open in the end, but code still doesn't run after I call this macro.

Comment: Use ThisWorkbook not ActiveWorkbook or set the relevent workbook; the active book may be changing without you realising

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work :/ The problem is definitely in the last 3 lines of my code though

Comment: My apologies to the first reply - using SaveCopyAs instead of SaveAs is exactly what my macro needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
Sub BackUp()

    Dim BackUpPath As String
        BackUpPath = "Your path"
        
    Dim BackUpFile As String
        BackUpFile = BackUpPath & "BackUp.xlsm"
        
        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=BackUpFile
        
End Sub
```

I call this at various times in my project to backup the document as required, this seems to work okay for me and my code will continue to run in the original workbook.

I also generate a unique filename each time and do not actually use "BackUp" as the name of the new workbook as this overwrites my previous backup so I would recommend doing something similar.

Comment: I got it to work! Turns out it's just as easy as using SaveCopyAs instead of the SaveAs method, and then deleting all the rubbish lines of code below that I wrote to try to make SaveAs work for my intended purpose. Thanks for the help!